# If a duplicate is suspected, shouldn't moderators close questions as such instead of deleting answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

The questions we are talking about:

- [Eclipse: Auto-align "=" in assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13936569/395857) (it's about Java)
- [Eclipse - "Align Field in Columns" C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30104147/395857) (it's about C/C++)

In Eclipse, each language has a different perspective, and perspectives have different features. Quite often a solution works for one language but not for the other languages. Hence the need for both questions. See [Are there any non-trivial examples of exact-duplicate answers to non-duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267318/178179) for details on why the questions are different.

---

If a duplicate is suspected, shouldn't moderators close questions as such instead of deleting answers?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30104147/395857):

[image]

I don't understand why the answer got deleted, while the question is still open. (well I do understand the latter since actually **it is not a duplicate in that case, as the OP said in the question**, but let's assume it is a duplicate)

---

Comment: Moderators don't necessarily have the knowledge required to ascertain a valid duplicate target (and even if we did - it's not really up to us to unilaterally go around and closing dupes). The reason you had two answers deleted was because you'd posted the same answer three times. One was left with a note suggesting what to do in the future apart from keep repeating your answer.

Comment: @JonClements Two different questions might have the same answer...

Comment: Then it still stands - if your answer is valid for all the three questions you posted on, then perhaps, the questions are duplicates and you should be casting your close votes to make sure two of the questions point to the best Q and set of A's

Comment: @JonClements "Eclipse - “Align Field in Columns for C/C++" is not the same question as "Does the Eclipse editor have an equivalent of Emacs's “align-regex”?".

Comment: Then the *exact* same answer probably isn't appropriate then? If you don't think the questions are duplicates, then amend your answer to be *specific* to each question as appropriate - don't just copy/paste the same answer.

Comment: @JonClements yes the exact same answer is appropriate. If you don't think so, just leave the answer and leave people (e.g. the OP) vote to decide for themselves.

Comment: If the exact same answer is appropriate, it's a dup.

Comment: to all: READ THE QUESTIONS!

Comment: Being the same exact answer doesn't necessarily mean it's a dup. For example, there could be two questions "what color is the sky" and "what color is the ocean".. in which "blue" would be the same exact answer to both, but the questions are different. So it has to be on case by case basis.

Comment: @CRABOLO That may be true for simple questions like that, but for the type of questions we get here, it's rare.

Comment: @ChrisF do you agree that the questions are different?

Comment: @CRABOLO That's more of a problem with insufficiently explained answers. "What color is the sky?" -> "Blue, because of the way light refracts off of the particles... blah blah." "What is Sir Lancelot's favorite color?" -> "Blue, as demonstrated in the film *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*."

Comment: @Doorknob can you explain to what extent my answer is insufficiently explained?

Comment: It's not. The questions are dups.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't have the domain knowledge for that. If you do you should be either a) voting to close or b) **tailoring your answer"". If you do that flag your answer for moderator attention and someone will look at undeleting it.

Comment: @Doorknob did you see that in the question I linked to, the OP specifically says "For Java I found this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936569/eclipse-auto-align-in-assignments", thereby indicating that the question is different (at least the  OP thinks so, and me too)?

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think much domain knowledge is needed to understand the questions, is just about moving text around.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If the exact same answer can be given for both questions, they are still duplicates.

Comment: @Doorknob it's a duplicate answer for two different questions.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you think the questions are different, then you should be able to show how they differ, by giving a different answer to each of them. If there is an answer on one question that can be copy/pasted to another, you should link the user who asked the question to that answer not by copy/pasting it, but by voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Doorknob is it so hard to comprehend that two different questions might have the same answer?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure, added. [One question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13936569/395857) is about Java, [the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30104147/395857) is about C/C++, and it turns out that the answer I propose works for both languages...

Comment: Actually, both are about eclipse, and the language edited is incidental, the way I see it.

Comment: @Deduplicator In Eclipse, each language has a different perspective, and perspectives have different features. Quite often a solution works for one language but not for the other languages. That's why the OP behind the C/C++ question said the question about Java didn't help him.

Comment: @ChrisF I added in the question everything needed regarding the domain knowledge.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Typically if you can copy and paste an answer to multiple questions, then it is a strong indicator that the questions are duplicates. If you don't believe they are duplicates, then you should be customizing the answer for each question.

Comment: @bluefeet Questions not duplicate as explained in this meta question. My answer is valid for both questions. If you think my answer should be customized, I would be glad to know how.

Comment: @CRABOLO, Franck: Can you weigh in on [this discussion about the existence of correct duplicate answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q)?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sure, done, thanks for posting the question there, please let me know if I can further clarify it.

Answer (score 11):

It's not for moderators to decide whether questions are duplicates - we don't necessarily have the domain knowledge. That's why users can vote to close - *they* have the domain knowledge required.

All we see is the identical answers - which are automatically flagged - and as a 3k+ user you should be voting to close.

As Jon points out in his comment, if the questions aren't duplicates then you should be tailoring your answer to the **specifics** of the question.

Comment: 1) Can you elaborate and explain why my answer isn't tailored out to the question? 2) regardless, isn't the community supposed to take care of voting?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt 1) your answer isn't tailored to the question because it triggered the automatic "duplicate answer" flag. Unless you tailored it within the 5 minute grace period of course, but I wouldn't get to see that. I don't know what you mean by your 2nd question.

Comment: 1) my answer is valid for both questions 2) I mean that it's up to the community to gauge the quality of the content: moderators shouldn't delete an answer.

Answer (score 9):

The core issue seems less about moderators closing as a duplicate, than it is about whether it is OK to post exactly the same answer multiple times. This aspect is well-covered in the Stack Exchange FAQ:

[Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/194636)

To summarize the FAQ Clean-Up answer, there is usually a *more correct* thing to do:

1. Are the questions duplicates of each other?
2. Are they promotional in any way?
3. Could the answers be more specific to each question?
4. The Community user will issue an automatic flag

The third point seems most relevant. Could you not customize the answer to the question (perhaps to a C/C++ example) and flag for a moderator to consider reinstating it? Always assuming you weren't intending to post 100 such answers.

Point 4 means there was always a risk a moderator would delete the answer. It is undeniably a judgement call, but moderators are entitled to make those calls. In light of the FAQ contents, it seems the right call.

It appears that the community expects *exact duplicate* answers to be highly exceptional. The examples provided are probably not sufficiently exceptional, on reflection.

Comment: Thanks. The answer  doesn't need to be customized for c++

Comment: I'm sure you're right. But it *could* be. And that would show willing, and respect for the community's stance on duplicate answers. Your call, naturally. Horse -> water.

Comment: I really don't see how it could be for c++ except changing the screen shot to c++.

Comment: Works for me (but I'm not a moderator on SO). Perhaps using the exact code in the question?

Comment: I think the community should decide, not the moderators. That used to be the point of the question :/

Comment: Yeah, nah. The activity raises a flag that moderators handle. FWIW, I think high-rep users did once handle dupe-answer flags as well as moderators, but that's changed now, probably because it didn't work well. Given the FAQ, chances are high the outcome would have been the same. Bit moot really.