# Is a question about a certain formatting of Java in Eclipse a duplicate of one about the same formatting of C++?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I saw two questions on Eclipse. Eclipse is an editor that is software developed to write code in many different programming languages such as Java, C, and C++.

**Question 1**: [Eclipse: Auto-align "=" in assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13936569/395857).

The question asks for the way to format *Java code* in Eclipse as follows:

```java
// Without formatting
private final String s1 = "10011";
private final String s2 = "01100";
private final String ones = "11111";
private final String zeros = "00000";


// With formatting
private final String s1    = "10011";
private final String s2    = "01100";
private final String ones  = "11111";
private final String zeros = "00000";
```

**Question 2**: [Eclipse - "Align Field in Columns" C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30104147/395857)

The question asks for the way to format *C/C++* in Eclipse as follows:

```cpp
// Without formatting
int mRect = 0;
int mSquare = 0;
bool isTriangle = false;

// With formatting
int  mRect      = 0;
int  mSquare    = 0;
bool isTriangle = false;
```

I believe these two questions are different because the first one asks about Java, the second one asks about C/C++. In Eclipse, each language has a different perspective, and perspectives have different features. This means that quite often a solution works for one language but not for the other languages.

For example, the following answer only works for Java:

> **Preferences** → **Java** → **Code Style** → **Formatter** → goto **Edit** and check the `Align fields in columns`:
>
> [image: Align fields in columns]

However, there could be a solution that works for both question (e.g. a plugin that is not specific to a language). Does this mean the two questions are duplicates?

(This is a follow-up to [If a duplicate is suspected, shouldn't moderators close questions as such instead of deleting answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307311/if-a-duplicate-is-suspected-shouldnt-moderators-close-questions-as-such-instea) focusing on whether the two questions are duplicates.)

Comment: @Zizouz212: Why? These are IDEs and programming languages we're talking about. No reason it shouldn't be on SO.

Comment: Well, if you find a duplicate just mark it as such.

Comment: @Deduplicator Not a duplicate... the other question is about how moderators should handle some general case.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the edit.